Using raw string in code snippet in R studio
It is possible in R to denote a string (a file path for example) as a raw string in R by using r"(...)".
I am trying to write a code snippet in R studio to automatically 'correct' pasted file paths, i.e convert '\' to '\\'. However when I try to use r"(...)" in a code snippet the '\' s aren't converted just removed.
Running in the console

`r"(C:\fake\directory\path)"`


gives

"C:\\fake\\directory\\path"


I have created a code snippet

snippet !

  `r r"($$)"`


But when I run

!C:\fake\directory\path<Shift-Tab>


The result is

C:fakedirectorypath


Am I missing something here or are raw strings just not able to be used in code snippets?
Also, if not is there another way of achieving what I want?

As you mention this is for pasting filepaths, you could define your snippet as:
snippet !
    `r sprintf("r\"(%s)\"", readClipboard())`

So that when you type !<shift+tab> in the Rstudio IDE it will insert the contents of the clipboard formatted as a raw string, e.g. r"(C:\fake\directory\path)"
Alternatively you can just use:
snippet !
    r"(${1:string})"

Then use !<shift+tab><ctrl+v>.
I don't think you can use $$ in a snippet for this because as you discovered, unescaped backslashes are stripped out when the text is inserted.

I think you have some misconceptions about R.
The code r"(C:\fake\directory\path)" is an R expression that evaluates to exactly the same thing as the R expression "C:\\fake\\directory\\path".  When R prints that value, it prints something that looks like the second version, not the first.
If you want R to print r"(C:\fake\directory\path)", you're going to have to go through some contortions to get it to happen.  I think this sequence of statements will do it in an R Markdown document:
```{r echo=FALSE}
  path <- "C:\\fake\\directory\\path"
```
Here it is:  `r cat('r"(', path, ')"', sep = "")`.

but I have to admit I haven't tried it to confirm.
